# Fetching a page's table data

Tags: php, fetch

I want to echo some data from another site similar to this question asked here [Getting data from another site with php via ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146608/getting-data-from-another-site-with-php-via-id).

There is a a row in the table I want to get and echo but can't make it echo anything.

Here is my code as I adapted it to the code from the above question but it doesn't work.

```
$content = "http://voucher.gov.gr/project/pedy-results/gid/14?search=PDNO-78256-114-20140722-120951";

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $content);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $body= curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    preg_match('#<tr class="row0"><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td>#Uis', $body, $resultmatch);

   $results = $resultmatch;

   foreach($results as $word)
   echo $word;
```

The array is created however but with no data in it. Any help/advice would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT
SOLUTION: Thank you all  for your help but I managed to make it work! This is the code:

```
preg_match('#<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td style="max-width:151px;"><strong>(.*)</strong></td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>(.*)<td>(.*)</td>#Uis', $body, $resultmatch);
```

This code is not the absolute correct answer because not only returns the info within the td's I want, it also returns the white spaces between them and that's because the code couldn't work without putting "(.*)" between the td's.

```
(...</td>(.*)<td>..)
```

so I had to live with it! However you can avoid it by ignoring the place the results with the white space were inserted in the array which in our case is `resultmatch[2,4,6,8,10...]` and so on. I hope my edit helped. The code can be further improved of course to avoid the white spaces being inserted into the array.

Comment: Have you debugged every step of the process? Do you get anything returned into `$body` for example?

Comment: @Raad yeap body returns the whole page correctly, i think the problem lies within the preg_match but i am not familiar with the expression.

Comment: If I'm correct (RegExp is not one of my strengths) then the match is looking for the row with the css class "row0" that contains 11 table cells that in turn contain numbers only. The page addressed has non-numeric content in the first 5 cells, hence no match.

Comment: @Raad so how do i declare that those 11 cells contain strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having identified that the curl is returning the page body correctly, you are correct in that the problem lies with the `preg_match`.

The match is looking for the row with the css class "row0" that contains 11 table cells, each of which has content that starts with a number followed by anything `([0-9\.]*)`.

The page addressed has content in the first 5 cells that is non-numeric at the start, hence no match, so to match this row, you could change the expression to:

```
'#<tr class="row0"><td>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td>(.*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td><td>([0-9\.]*)</td>#Uis'
```

As I said in my comment, Regular Expressions are not one of my strong skills (hence I got it slightly wrong in my comment), so whilst I think this will work, you may have to tweak it.

I find the RegExp "fiddle" site http://regex101.com/ really useful.

Comment: Your answer really helped me get to it! Thanks!

Comment: @fotis179 - if you think my answer did the trick, please click the big white tick =)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the $body there is a lot of unnecessary whitespace and line breaks that prevent your expression to find matches.

In order to match the alphanumeric string you need something like that '(.*?)\u'

note the u before the end, that allows for matching unicode characters.

So I think this is what you need:

```
$content = "http://voucher.gov.gr/project/pedy-results/gid/14?search=PDNO-78256-114-20140722-120951";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $content);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$body= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//you need to strip whitespace and line breaks first
$body = preg_replace('~>[\s|\r\n]+<~', '><', $body); 
$body = preg_replace('#\n( *?)#', '', $body); 
preg_match('#<tr class=\"row0\"><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td(.*?)>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>#u', $body, $resultmatch);
var_dump($resultmatch);
```

The result of the above is this:

```
array (size=13)
  0 => string '<...>' (length=398)
  1 => string 'Στερεάς Ελλάδας' (length=29)
  2 => string 'Φθιώτιδας' (length=18)
  3 => string ' style="max-width:151px;"' (length=25)
  4 => string '<strong>PDNO-78256-114-20140722-120951</strong>' (length=47)
  5 => string '
            22/07/2014                                    12:09:51                                ' (length=99)
  6 => string 'Επιλεχθείς' (length=20)
  7 => string '30' (length=2)
  8 => string '30' (length=2)
  9 => string '30' (length=2)
  10 => string '10' (length=2)
  11 => string '100' (length=3)
  12 => string '1                                ' (length=33)
```

Comment: Really good answer here for stripping the white spaces. Will try it out when i find the time! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML elements.

Using the DOM API would be less error prone.

You could replace the "preg_match" line with:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($body);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//tr[@class="row0"][1]/td');

$results = array();
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $value = trim($node->nodeValue);
    if( ctype_digit($value) ) {
        $results[] = $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```